# Alternative to isdigit to read numbers larger than 9?

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm currently working on a program in C that takes input from the user using `scanf`. I want the program to terminate is the user enters something other than a number.

Currently, I'm using the following code:

```
 while(scanf("%c", &value) == 1) {
       if(isdigit(value)) {
          scanf("%c", &value);
          push(&head, value);
          count++;
     }
     else {
       break;
     }
   }
```

I'm using `isdigit` to check if the input is a number between 0-9, but this poses problems if the user were to input something like... "52".

Is there an alternative to `isdigit` that can handle this? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You can't input `"52"` with `scanf("%c", &value)`.

Comment: Generally speaking it's better to read a full line of input and then parse afterwards, for just this reason.

Comment: You *could* read in a string (character array, using the `%s` format) and then check it using `strspn(str,"0123456789")` to see if it's all digits. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strspn/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't store "52" into char instead of try this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int myisdigit(char *str)
{
    while(*str)
    {
        if(!isdigit(*str))
            return 0;

        str++;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char str[10];

    scanf("%s",str);

    if(myisdigit(str))
        printf("digit");
    else
        printf("non digit");

    return 0;
}
```

You can also change myisdigit to

```
int myisdigit(char *str)
{

    while(*str)
    {
        if( ! ( ( ( *str ) >= '0' ) && ( (*str) <='9' ) ) )
            return 0;

        str++;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: regarding; `scanf("%s",str);`  When using the input format specifiers: `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer.  Because those format conversions always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the attendant undefined behavior.

Comment: regarding: `int _isdigit(char *str)`  The compiler will prepend a underscore to the function name, so the function: `isdigit()` can be mistaken for your `_isdigit()`  and if the compiler doesn't have a problem, the human reader of your code can/will have a problem. To avoid any misunderstanding, suggest using a function name like: `myIsDigit()`